# Ctrl-C is ignored by pppd when put in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals, ppp, pppd

I'm trying to connect to GPRS network through a serial port connected GSM modem.

When I call `/usr/sbin/pppd call <peer_name>` from the command line, it correctly receives and handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from keyboard.

But when I put the exact same command in an empty shell script (with or without the shebang `#!` at the top), `chmod +x` it and run it from the shell prompt, then `pppd` starts to run - But it totally ignores <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key combination. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> works normally though.

This is the contents of the `pppd` peer file

```
nodetach
dump
connect "connect_script"
disconnect "disconnect_script"
/dev/ttyS0
noauth
```

I tested another peer file which I had created to connect to a PPTP VPN server - with the same result. PPTP does not need a chat script, so I'm ruling out problems with `chat` command or serial port link properties.

OS is debian 7.

Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: Can someone reproduce and confirm this problem on their machine? On my machine this problem only applies to `pppd`. As far as I checked, no other program has this issue.

Comment: I would but I do not have a GSM modem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is a bug specific to `pppd` version 2.4.5, which is the one that comes with Debian 7. I tested versions 2.4.4 and 2.4.6 (which is the latest as of now) on the same and other machines and they work as expected. `pppd` package seems to have a lot of signal handler manipulation code in it, which I guess could lead to these kind of bugs. I'm just happy that it's been fixed by now.